# Conectar Visual Studio Code con Github

Tags: git, github, vscode

Disculpen pero he buscado y buscado videos de como conectar mi visual Studio a Github pero solo encuentro videos viejos , con versiones anteriores del VS , llevo un buen tratando de hacerlo pero no he podido , si alguien me puede orientar en esto le agradeceré!

Logre encontrar en los settings este apartado donde puedo poner esto:

```
 Git: Default Clone Directory
The default location to clone a git repository.
 https://github.com/equipo-dinamita/spotify
```

pero no se que paso sigue.

Comment: ¿ Que significa `conectar a Github` ? ¿ Usar VSCode como editor por defecto de Git ? ¿ Que las órdenes `pull` y `push` usen GitHub como remoto ?

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo:

Primero si ya tienes instalado VSC, abre tu consola de Git y posisionate en tu proyecto.

Listo!? ahora vamos a escribir el siguiente comando

```
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

Ahora solo vamos a hacer un nuevo `commit` sin comentar y en cuanto lo hagamos nos abrira VSC donde agregaremos el mensaje del nuevo commit, solo basta con guardar y cerrar, y el commit estara listo.

De esta manera quedara VSC configurado globalmente si solo lo queremos para el proyecto actual basta con cambiar **global ** por local.

Y ya!

Suerte!

Comment: tal vez deberías de especificar que primero debería de tener git instalado y de dónde debería de instalarlo.